# Scrape Data from "div" class

Tags: xml, r, web-scraping

I tried and am able scrape data from `td` class using the script below:

```
 nArticles <- getNodeSet(pagetree,"//*/td[@class='bg1 W1']//*/li[@class='LI2 font28 C bold W1']") #current price
 current.price <- xmlValue(nArticles[[1]])
```

Now I have a websource like below:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">
            <ul class="BlockItemIndex" style="width:123px; height:92px">
                    <li class="font12 I1">
                            Index
                    </li>
                    <li class="I1" style="font:bold 20px Arial">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblIndex">21,549.28</span></li>
                    <li class="I1" style="font:normal 15px Arial">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblChange"><span class="pos bold">+70.56 (0.33%)</span></span></li>
                    <li class="I1">
                            <span class="font12">Turnover</span>&nbsp;<span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblTurnover">70.41B</span></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="seperate"></div>
    <div style="float: left;">
            <ul class="BlockItemChange" style="width:75px">
                    <li class="font12 I1">
                            High
                    </li>
                    <li class="I2">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblHigh">21,569.74</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="BlockItemChange" style="width:75px; margin-top:2px;">
                    <li class="font12 I1">
                            Low
                    </li>
                    <li class="I2">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblLow">21,302.19</span></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="seperate"></div>
    <div style="float: left;">
            <ul class="BlockItemChange" style="width:75px">
                    <li class="font12 I1">
                            Open
                    </li>
                    <li class="I2">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblOpen">21,339.02</span></li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="BlockItemChange" style="width:75px; margin-top:2px;">
                    <li class="font12 I1">
                            Prev Close
                    </li>
                    <li class="I2">
                            <span id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_cphContent_lblPreClose">21,478.72</span></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to pick up `21,549.28`, and I tried the following:

```
nArticles <- getNodeSet(pagetree,"//*/ul[@class='BlockItemChange']//*/li[@class='I2']")
```

But fails. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know what you're using to determine the value you're interested in, but

```
query = '//ul[@class="BlockItemIndex"]/li[2]/span/text()'
xpathSApply(xml, query, xmlValue)
```

picks out all BlockItemIndex elements that have at least two li elements containing a span element. Since all li elements have the same class, it doesn't help to specify one. I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with `*`; I think it's redundant with `//`. Later in your query, `//` isn't what you want, you're interested in immediate descendants of the BlockItemClass element.