# scrape data from "td"class within another "td" class

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping

I have a question similar to my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9396853/scrape-data-from-div-class) one.

I have a part of HTML attached here:

```
<td class="LIGHTGrey">
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td><font class="CONTENT">1%</font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><font class="CONTENT">*Not applicable to Guaranteed Funds and Class B Units*</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td>
```

I want to extract the `1%` in the forth line using `XML` in R, I wrote something like:

```
 query = '//td[@class="LIGHTGrey"]/tbody/tr/td/font[@class="CONTENT"]/text()'
 temp <- xpathSApply(doc, query, xmlValue)
```

But the temp returned `NULL`, what did I do wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing `table`. Try this:

```
query = '//td[@class="LIGHTGrey"]/table/tbody/tr/td/font[@class="CONTENT"]/text()'
```